# Delete rows from DataFrame, applying a start date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing some data from Brazil's Central Bank, but I wanna apply a start date in pandas dataframe.

[image]

```
df = dolar
dolar.index
```

[image]

I'm having some problems trying to delete rows.

When I try to delete rows using :

```
dolar.drop(dolar.iloc[:3000,:],axis=0)
KeyError: "['valor'] not found in axis"
```

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: What rows are you trying to delete?

Comment: I'm trying to delete every row before 2000-01-01

Comment: `df = df[df.index.date > datetime.date(1999,12,31)]`

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you so much !! I tried for hours .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second way, to complement @Vishal's answer.  This uses slice notation on the DatetimeIndex.  We can provide just the year, not year-month-day:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='1999-12-27', end='2000-01-03')
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [*range(8)]}, index=dates)

df = df.loc['2000': ]
print(df)


            data
2000-01-01     5
2000-01-02     6
2000-01-03     7
```